# Correct input string was not in correct format with an array list

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created an `Array list` in `c#` and would like users to be able to add to the list through data entry on the form.  I have the entered the following code but encounter the error `"Input string was not in the correct format."` Not sure how to correct it to enable user input.

```
Arraylist hotelRooms = new ArrayList

Public void AddCurrentItem ()
{
  HotelRoom hotelRooms = new HotelRoom 
 Int.Parse(textboxRoomNumber.Text),comboBoxRoomType. Text, int.Parse (comboBoxFloorNumber.Text), comboBoxSeaView. Text, decimal.Parse (textBoxRoomRate. Text), comboBoxBooked. Text); 
hotelRooms. Add(hotelRooms)

}
```

Comment: What does your HotelRoom class look like? Are the missing parantheses aftr New HotelRoom just a typo?

Comment: make sure that textboxes you are parsing to int , contains digit only

Comment: use [try-catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0yd65esw.aspx), Luke :-)

Comment: Can you please provide a sample that can compile? Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: When some one uses ArrayList one unicorn dies in the Universe

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse(string) will throw a ArgumentFormatException if the string is empty.

This example will throw an exception stating that the input string was not in correct format.

```
string myString = "";
int i = int.Parse(myString);
```

So what you have to do is verify the inputs you use in the HotelRoom constructor. You could possibly expand the inputs to variables before hitting the HotelRoom constructor.

Something like:

```
int roomNumber = 0;
int.TryParse(textboxRoomNumber.Text, out roomNumber);

string roomType = comboBoxRoomType.Text;
```

Then before instantiating the HotelRoom object do some checking: (some code omitted for brewity)

```
if (roomNumber > 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(roomType))
{
    HotelRoom h = new HotelRoom(roomNumber, roomType);
    hotelRooms.Add(h);
}
else
{
    // return the variables to the ui, so that the user can do another 
    // selection if something is missing or wrong.
}
```